# How to modify this circuit that controls servos with audio jack to control switches

Tags: mosfet, ac, dc

A circuit is given at

http://makezine.com/projects/make-34/smartphone-servo/

[image]

that controls two independent servos from a three pin audio jack.
How do I modify the circuit so it can control two independent switches and the switches have only two possible states-which are completely off or completely on? The switches will be on the digital input pins on an arduino Uno.
What would be the new circuit diagram?

So there is no debouncing- and the transition from on to off(or off to on) for each switch is clean. Which means when some audio file is played the switch stays on completely on for the duration of while that audio is being played,and  when a different audio file is played the switch stays off completely on for the duration of while that audio is being played.

I thought about using some mosfet to do this that replaces the servo in the diagram and uses the same software to control the servo as the mosfet-is that correct?-if so can you recommend the correct mosfet.
 As far as I understand the same oscillating audio, thats used for the servos there, can be used to control the mosfet (on or off state) -as I require- because the capacitors will smooth the AC from the audio to constant DC. 
It seems using a transistor, like the bc547, instead of mosfet will not saturate the transistor or it wont behave like a switch.

I think my answer using mosfet is correct but I would like confirmation that it is.

I am assuming there is no crosstalk because it wasnt mention with that servo circuit.

Comment: You are asking people to help you please do them the courtesy of putting the circuit up here.

Comment: Many of your claims in the last paragraph are not correct, but for us to actually answer your original question, you have to tell us much more about the "switches". What are they switching? Do they handle AC or DC? Power or just signal? Common-ground with B1 or isolated? etc... We need to know load parameters in order to do things like size the parts (like the transistors in your ask).

Comment: @DrFriedParts Updated the question

Comment: This is ridiculous! You want a circuit that controls two things, so you pick a random hack circuit on the Internet that controls two things that are completely different, and expect us to tell you how to "modify" it? Tell us what you really want to do, without presupposing a solution.

Comment: @Dave Tweed Wrong-I didnt pick it at random. If you think the answer is easy then I would like to know it please

Comment: Step back and explain what you really want to accomplish.  Leave out your hallucinations about how to accomplish it.  If you knew how to do it, you wouldn't be here asking.  By presenting a totally inappropriate starting point, you make answering this question too difficult because a bunch of nonsense has to be dispelled first.  Fix this or be closed.  The process has been started, so the clock is ticking.

Comment: I dont think the question is any less ridiculous than controlling two servos -with a smart phone. I want to know how to control two switch with a smartphone.

Comment: And the circuit presented there does it with minimal hardware which to me is interesting

Comment: @Pete Conceptually, controlling servos and switches is the same (with the common word "two") but it may not be implemented the same way. And usually, you do not control a switch, but rather you control something with a switch.

Comment: I don't see any change to the question.  Tick, tock, tick, tock.

Comment: The circuit works with two servos because the servos have a bit of "smarts" and are flexible enough to accept audio instead of the expected sharp edge pulse width modulated signals that are normally fed to remote control servos.  You must provide something with similar "smarts" to provide your switch output.  Just slapping transistor on the earphone output won't get you very far.

Comment: The capacitors (as installed it that circuit) will NOT smooth the AC to DC.  The way they are used removes any DC that may be present.

Comment: If you want a smartphone and an Arduino to communicate with each other, there are much easier ways to go about it, and *MANY* examples already on the Internet. This is not a design service.

Comment: @Davetweed also im interested in the theory of how this circuit work too, to widen my knowledge on eletrical engineering

Comment: Well, THAT question has been answered by JIm Dearden below.

Answer (score 1):

First, analyse what's actually happening in this circuit. A digital pulse is being passed through a coupling capacitor. What is important is that the load (resistance) must be high enough so the pulse shape isn't altered significantly.

[image]

The basic circuit is an RC differentiator. Even with a high resistance load you will get some droop in the voltage.

The article states the output is about 1V.

**How it controls the servo.**

The position on the screen is converter to a pulse width in order to control the servo. This would vary from about 1 mS (0 degrees) to 2mS (180 degrees) with a 1.5mS pulse for the neutral (90 degrees) position. The pulse frequency is about 50Hz (period 20mS) - all this is pretty standard stuff with the pulses being handled by the circuit inside the servo.

What you are asking for is to convert these pulses into switch signals. **Its not a simple 'turn on a bjt or mosfet' type circuit.**

*"I think my answer using mosfet is correct but I would like confirmation that it is."*

I can confirm that your answer is incorrect for the above reasons.

Comment: I guess you would need a circuit that replaces the electronics in the servo. Something like a RC filter that takes the pulses-and gives a constant DC voltage then put that into the transistor

Comment: Its certainly doable  - google pulse width discriminator circuits. You need to make a decision on what timing constitutes ON or OFF and how you handle the change (some form of hysteresis?). Then you'll need to remember the last change (flip flop) as your circuit will be outputting a new value every 20mS.

Comment: So if its a square wave pulse you can put that into an low pass RC filter-than that gives an analog voltage to turn on the transistor. Yes I'll read about  discriminator circuits-i dont know about them so far

Comment: Remember that the pulse has just come through a capacitor (AC coupled) - to return it to a **digital pulse** you need to make it operate some form of electronic switching circuit (eg - a bjt). Make sure the 'load' seen by the pulse is high enough.

Comment: nope - the app produces a pulse like signal every 20mS (1mS-2mS duration), not a sinewave or a squarewave. This comment facility is not for conversations or additional (supplementary) questions. What I suggest is you take some time to think about it, do some research (the stack may well have the circuit your after) and then ask another question (or questions) in the stack remembering that its not a free design service.